# Doctrine2 Querybuilder bitwise and

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I would like to use a bitwise comparison in my Doctrine2/Symfony2 QueryBuilder.
I tried

```
->andWhere('n.sharingenabled & 1')
```

And

```
->andWhere('BIT_AND(n.sharingenabled, 1)')
```

but they both threw the following error

> QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 327: Error: Expected =, <,
>   <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '&'

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to compare the `BIT_AND` result to something ... for example :

```
->andWhere('BIT_AND(n.sharingenabled, 1) > 0')
```

Comment: I tried `->andWhere('i.flags & 1 = 1')` and this didn't work either. Using your solution worked for me!!

Comment: thank you so much for this... saved me a lot of time!

Comment: How to use it with groupby? I get `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 435 near 'BIT_AND(u.cl': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable.`