# AND between integers in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have in database a column notified, that contains a integer representing a binary, such 001 as 1, 111 as 7 and it's combinations. I need verify if one bit is activated, for this, in PHP I use AND, but in a query of doctrine 2 I can't use that by default because I obtain: "Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'AND'". How can I resolve this problem???
Thanks

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15854653/209585